# Vue 2 set data or prop or anything on child slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have following components:

*Child.vue*

```
<template>
  <li>
      {{ idx }}
  </li>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  data () {
    return {
      idx: 0
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

*Parent.vue*

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <slot />
  </nav>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  mounted() {
    //
    const slots = (this.$scopedSlots.default ? this.$scopedSlots.default(this.$attrs) : []);
    for (let i = 0; i < slots!.length; i++) {
      const s = slots![i];
      // Essential magic must happen here, but it does not :(
      if (s.data?.attrs) slots![i].data!.attrs!.idx = i;
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

*Controls.vue*

```
<template>
  <Parent>
   <Child />
   <Child />
   <Child />
  </Parent>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import Parent from './Parent.vue';
import Child from './Child.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: { Parent, Child }
});
</script>
```

So as the outcome I wish every Child to know its position or index, but what I get is `000`,
so setting data on child component doesn't work for some reason.
Any hint on improving typescript code are also welcome.

Here is codepen in js: https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-vue-forked-focjc1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to break the governing principle of slots.
They were created as a mechanism to transfer template responsibility from the slot bearer component (in our example: `<Parent />`) to the slot content provider component (in our example: `<Controls />`).

More precisely, the main purpose of `<slot>Default HTML</slot>` (inside `<Parent />`) is to either render `Default HTML` when used as

```html
<Parent />
```

, in which case `Default HTML`'s parent is `<Parent />`, or to render `Replacement HTML` when used as

```html
<Parent>Replacement HTML</Parent>
```

, in which case `Replacement HTML`'s parent is the slot content provider (`<Controls />`).

We can't tell `Parent.vue`: *"you know what, even if you're not in charge of providing the slot contents anymore, I still want you to meddle with it"*.
I mean, we can try, but slots were not developed for this purpose and there's no public API to hook into the rendering process of slots. Even if we figure out a way to do it today, we have no guarantee it won't break in the future, without warning.

If we find ourself needing anything from `<Parent />` while crafting the slot contents (in `<Controls />`) we can pass it from Parent to Controls using slot scope:

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
  <nav>
    <slot :foo="foo" />
  </nav>
</template>

<!-- Controls.vue -->
<Parent>
  <template #default="{ foo }">
    // use Parent's `foo` inside Controls
  </template>
</Parent>
```

---

In our specific case, let's declare `idx` prop on `<Child />` and populate it from `<Controls />`

```html
<!-- Controls.vue -->
<template>
  <Parent>
    <Child v-for="n in 3" :key="n" :idx="n - 1" />
  </Parent>
</template>
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-vue-forked-wiv3t3?file=/src/Child.vue).